# Scheme: Cons a function to list in macro

Tags: scheme

I would like to make a macro:

```
(define-syntax MyMacro
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((MyMacro a b)  (cons a b))
  )
) 
(display (MyMacro + (list 1 2 3 4)))
```

and I get,

```
#<subr +> 1 2 3 4)
```

But, what I actually want is sum of 1 2 3 4.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

**Update:**

Actually my problem is about meep:

I would like to use a function "at-every" (at-every arg1 functions...).

And I define a function which make use of "in-point" function

```
(define (makeBzSeries n)
(in-point
 (vector3
    (- (- (/ sx 2) (/ conThick 2)) (* obserR (cos (nToTheta n))))
    (* obserR (sin (nToTheta n)))
    0
 )
 (to-appended
   (string-append "bz" (number->string n) )
   output-bfield-z))
)
```

What I want is

```
(at-every 2 (makeBzSeries 0) (makeBzSeries 1) ... (makeBzSeries 600))
```

I have try to use apply and map, but (makeBzSeries n) is a procedure instead of value. Is there any method to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern syntax in syntax rules works in a way that the matches `a` == `+` and `b` == `(list 1 2 3 4)` are inserted in their place so:

```
(define lst (list 1 2 3 4)) 
(MyMacro + lst) ; ==>
(cons + lst)
```

This happens before the code runs. The imporant think to know is that your macro will only see what is passed as code. In my example above `lst` is the data the macro has to do with as what it evaluates to comes later. So imagine that you want a literal only version:

```
(define-syntax my-macro
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((my-macro function (arg ...)) (function arg ...))
    ((my-macro . rest) (error "invalid use of my-macro"))))

(my-macro + (1 2 3 4)) ; ==>
(+ 1 2 3 4)            ; ==> 10
```

This will not work with `lst`:

```
(my-macro + lst)            ; ==> "Invalid use of my-macro"
(my-macro + (list 1 2 3 4)) ; ==> complains about function list is not a number
```

Note that you have a function called `apply` that does what you want:

```
(apply + (list 1 2 3 4)) ; ==> 10
```

Comment: thank you very much. I have update the post. would you please have look.

Comment: @yikai `(apply at-every 2 (map makeBzSeries (range 601))`?

Comment: I think the failure when I tried to use apply previously is due to misunderstanding of apply function. Thank you.